# Reference of proving the existence of $\partial_t u -\Delta u = f(x,t)$ by Rothe's method ( method of lines or semidiscretization)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request

Recently, I read a book about PDE which is written by Chinese. In it, there is a proof about the existence of
$$
\partial_t u -\Delta u = f(x,t)
$$
by Rothe's method. But there is a step I can't understand. So, I want to know whether there is any reference which has similar proof. Since I fail to find it in google, so, I asked here. Thanks for any help.

---

In 64th page, I can't understand the inequality (3.2.12)
$$
||u^{m_{_l}} - u ||_{W^{1,1}_2~(Q_T)} < \frac{1}{l}. \tag{1}
$$
In my view,  form $\{u^m\}_{m=1}^\infty$ is bounded in $W^{1,1}_2~(Q_T)$, we only get
$$
u^m\rightharpoonup u
$$
But (1) means convergence in norm.

Comment: Evans' book uses semidiscetizatiion to prove the existence of a solution of the heat equation, he calls it Galerkin approximation. See Chapter 7 of the book.

Comment: @aziiri  Seemly, they are different method. The Galerkin mehod in Evans' book is to use finite dimension to approximate the infinite dimension. But the Rothe's method is to do difference to the time $t$.

Comment: Are you referring to this book: 《椭圆与抛物型方程引论》 by 伍卓群、尹景学、王春朋? If so, could you please elaborate which step you didn't understand?

Comment: @WentaoHu  谢谢啦，时间有点久，我记得不是很清楚了。就是64页最后一个不等式实际上意味着$u^{m_{_l}}$ 强收敛到$u$, 但是如果只用$u^m$的有界性，只能得到$u^{m_{_l}}$ 弱收敛到$u$。我估计是用了$C_0^\infty$在$\mathring W^{1,1}_2$中的稠密性，不过后来不了了之，没想了。我修改了问题，里面说明了一下，但是我英语有点挫，，

Comment: @lanse7pty 实在抱歉，这个我也没弄懂。